# Twilio video: How can I overlay the local camera video over the remote video feed?

Tags: html, css, video, twilio

I'm exploring the possibility of doing one-on-one video-chat functionality in our web-app using the Twilio-video functionality (I know it's beta).

I'm trying to get a layout something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/0p8s1omp/82/

```
.MainContainer {position:relative;}
.remote-container{
    height: 400px;
    background-color: black; 
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.local-container{
    height: 20%;
    width:20%;
    background-color: green;    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

The idea being to overlay the local video track over the remote camera's feed.

When I try a similar HTML/CSS structure in my app, it almost works (I think) - the local camera track seems to laid out "underneath", the remote.
When I inspect and hover over the local element in the source, Chrome shows a shaded rectangle where the local video should be, but it's not visible - I can only see the remote video.

I tried setting the Z-index of the remote to -1, but that didn't seem to work.

Is this an issue with Twilio-video, or with my HTML/CSS (maybe there's something I have to do to get video elements to lay out the way I want?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked up something that seems to work, but not really sure if it's the right approach.  The code below is scala.js (beware, I'm even worse at Scala than I am at Javascript), but you get the general idea.

```
def onInvitedToConversation = (conversation: TwilioConversation) => {
  log.info("invited to conversation: " + conversation)
  onParticipantConnected(conversation, (participant: TwilioParticipant) => {
    log.info("participant connected: " + participant.identity)
    kopi.showScreen(
      div(
        position.relative,
        div(id:="remote-media",
          position.relative
        ),
        div(id:="local-media",
          position.absolute,
          top:="10px",  // position the local media at top left
          left:="10px",
          height:="20%" // size the local media to 20%
        )
      )
    )

    participant.media.attach("#remote-media")
    conversation.localMedia.attach("#local-media")

    // the video element is added to the div by the "attach" call above
    val video = jQuery("#local-media video")
    video.attr("height", "100%")

  }: Unit)

}
```

Everything here is pretty much the obvious code, except the height attribute  on the video element - but that's what makes it work, for whatever reason.  Without the height attribute, the local-media video will just be whatever size Twilio gives it by default.